# Routerguard and other 'security features' of Angular and javascript secure?

Tags: javascript, angular, security

I was under the assumption that all javascript could essentially be modified client side to access things that are only protected through javascript level 'protection', for instance if you have a check with PHP on if a user is logged it, it wont render at all client side but Angular AuthGuard and similar styles of 'protection' are more like 'dont go here but if you really want to you probably can'

Is this correct, and it would just be super convoluted to get past these types of guards but real data that needs to be protected should just gets requested with a token or login data sent from the client to the server?

I'm just trying to understand what security features (if any) are provided with Angular or javascript in general, but was always under the assumption any javascript can be modified by the client, client side

Comment: if you're asking about server-security (data/ops), JS has nothing to do with it. Client side validation/navigation is a user convenience, not a security aspect. You have no control over how such JS and indeed how your URLs will be used by a given client.

Comment: Yeah, so any sensitive data or areas that I wanted protected should be authenticated properly to the server, so routerguard is just more streamline

Comment: On the client-side, all validation/authorization/security are only conveniences for a better user experience. All data must be re-validated/re-authenticated/protected on the server-side.

Comment: yes. it's very simple: don't give out what you don't want others to have.

Comment: No worries, I was under the impression that was the case but just wondered about authguard but would never have sensitive data client side, thanks for the responses guys appreciate it

Comment: important questions, glad to help